# how to run python script without typing 'python ...'

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to run a python script without explicitly having to call "python" every time in my shell. I've tried to add the shebang #!/path/to/python but this does not seem to work. Does anyone know a work around this? Many thanks.

Comment: "this does not seem to work."  The question does not seem to have  a specific error message.  Without the specific error, we don't seem to be able to guess what went wrong.

Comment: It's called the shebang #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Also 'chmod a+x' the file, and add the directory to the PATH

Comment: Which is your DE?

Comment: Could somebody please explain what the PATH is? And how I can add my directory to it?

Comment: @St4rb0y This related question covers it nicely, though it's not about Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands The mechanism is the same regardless of the scripting language.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You've got to add the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then make the script executable:

```
chmod +x foo
```

Then you can run it like any other executable:

```
./foo
```

And a note from Homer6: if you're editing the file from windows and invoking it on linux, you may run into the cryptic "No such file or directory" error. It's due to the line endings of the lines being CRLF instead of LF. If you convert them to LF, the script will execute as expected. Notepad++ > View > Show Symbols > Show End of Line to show the EOL characters. And Notepad++ > Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix Format to convert all line endings to use LF. Alternatively, you can use the `dos2unix` tool (`dos2unix foo.py`), which is present on most Linux systems.

Comment: As a side note: it's better to use `/usr/bin/env` than the path to Python in the shebang line: if you hard-code a path, the script will stop working if Python is ever moved… But so long as Python is on `$PATH`, `/usr/bin/env` will work.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, `env` could be located elsewhere as well. But yes, that's much less propable than running the script on some other distro that happens to put python somewhere else.

Comment: That's true. But I don't know of any other, more portable, way of doing it.

Comment: Another note: if you're editing the file from windows and invoking it on linux, you may run into the cryptic ": No such file or directory" error. It's due to the line endings of the lines being CRLF instead of LF. If you convert them to LF, the script will execute as expected. Notepad++ > View > Show Symbols > Show End of Line to show the EOL characters. And Notepad++ > Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix Format to convert all line endings to use LF.

Comment: On gvim for windows, I think `:set ff=unix` then saving fixes this issue.

Comment: on Mac I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` and it worked

Answer (score 7):

It didn't really apply to your personal scripts but as you are quoting `beets`, note that it is also possible to automate this action when you are distributing your packages, thanks to [setuptools `entry_point`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) option.
So if you are distributing a package like `myModule` and want to make the `main_function()` function accessible via typing `mymodulescript` in the console you would probably add something like this to your `setup.py` file :

```
setup(
    # your other arguments ..
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mymodulescript = myModule:main_function'
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a line at the top of your script:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env python
   ```
2. Rename your script from `script_name.py` to `script_name`
3. make the script executable: `chmod +x script_name`

The line at the top selects the same `python` that you get when typing python at the prompt. You can also specify a direct path:

```
#!/opt/python/3.6/bin/python
```

Comment: In addition, you need to add the location of the script to the PATH variable. otherwise you will need to execute it as ./script_name

Comment: why did you suggest changing the name of the file? is there any repercussions of not doing that?

Comment: @VishalSingh The repercussion is that you have to type three extra characters to invoke the script, and for other it `script_name` (which should reflect the function it performs) less clear. There are primitive OS-es that need such extensions to determine which interpreter to start the Unix/Linux and their shells have long ago solved that in a better way. Leaving the extension makes you look inexperienced.

Comment: Also, to paraphrase Charles Duffy, we don't use `ls.elf` or `emacs.bin` so why should your own commands have an extension?

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround could be to use an alias defined in the .bashrc :

e.g. add the following line in your .bachrc file :

```
alias mypythonalias="python mypyrhonfile.py"
```

type in terminal :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and then you may simply type:

```
mypythonalias
```

to execute the python file.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are able to run /path/to/python on your terminal. And make sure you have given execute permission for your python file. You can give permission for the file by

```
chmod +x mypythonfile.py
```

Comment: this is a bit late, but where do I put the chmod command...in command prompt? Thanks

Comment: @lucyb Yes, `chmod` is a Unix command which you would typically type at your shell prompt.