# How do I run a shell script without using "sh" or "bash" commands?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, sh

I have a shell script which I want to run without using the "sh" or "bash" commands. For example:

Instead of: `sh script.sh`

I want to use: `script.sh`

How can I do this?

P.S. (i) I don't use shell script much and I tried reading about aliases, but I did not understand how to use them.

(ii) I also read about linking the script with another file in the PATH variables. I am using my  university server and I don't have permissions to create a file in those locations.

Comment: The answers indicate how to make the script executable, but don't seem to cover how to make it accessible.  For that, create yourself a bin directory - `$HOME/bin` - if you don't already have one, add it to your PATH (near the front).  Put the scripts (and any other programs) you want to execute directly without specify the pathname in here, or symlinks in here to where the actual programs are.

Comment: After you follow the answer(s) below, to drop the ".sh" you can rename the file: `mv example.sh example` and then `example` should work on its own.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

Add a "shebang" at the top of your file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And make your file executable (`chmod +x script.sh`).

Finally, modify your path to add the directory where your script is located:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/appropriate/directory
```

(typically, you want `$HOME/bin` for storing your own scripts)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I tried that out. Now I can run it without the "sh" command. But I still have to prefix the command with "./" which I don't want to. :)

Comment: See comments about the path. You need to put your script in a directory which you have to append to your PATH.

Comment: it didn't work in my case.
but `source script.sh` worked fine, or rather 
`source <filename_without_any_extension_type>`

Comment: `source ./my-cool-script` (or `. ./my-cool-script`) will pollute the current shell session with any variables defined in the script. Sourcing should not be used unless you want to explicitly modify the shell session by setting environment vars, changing the directory, etc. Really terrible bugs could result otherwise, as variables from one script execution, if done via sourcing, could affect another script execution.

Comment: If you are sure the script folder is in PATH, and it still does not work without `./`, then you may have a name collision.  Try renaming.

Comment: you'll still get a `command not found` error if you are in the script directory and not including `./` . simply change to a different directory, and  as long as the script is in your $PATH variable, it will work.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, and it was a naming collision as [chorbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761682/chorbs) advised.

Comment: use "alias demo = 'bash demo.sh'", then you don't have to write "./". Just simply write 'demo' and bang...

Comment: If you're receiving command not found the problem is not name collision, it would execute the wrong script/binary if was so. You may be setting you're path wrongly. You can `cd` to where the script is and issue `PATH=$PATH:$PWD` it would work

Comment: Also you have to set the PATH on the same `bash` session that you're executing. If you open a new terminal or another bash, or type bash on the same session your PATH is gone. If your script is trying to be executed by another command you may need to export it with `export PATH` so commands that run on your bash receives the up to date PATH

Comment: what is the zsh shebang? How do I find the right path for zsh?

Comment: @Daniel `type zsh` wild print it if it's in your `PATH`. If you are already running `zsh`, you can also try `echo "$SHELL"`

Comment: @tripleee thanks! not sure how I missed this reply... `which zsh` works too!

Comment: How can `chmod +x script.sh` be done via a shell script, so it doesn't have to be done manually for several files?

Comment: @Daniel Please post a new separate question instead. Nobody will see your comments down here except by accident, and you are drifting further and further off-topic. Also, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: To clarify (which I don't think is off-topic): "And make your file executable (chmod +x script.sh)." How can that be done in a shell script, so that running that script, executes that command, just like if one was to type it in Terminal?

Comment: On my Android shell (which is LineageOS), the shell is /bin/sh, which I must use the `sh` command to run a shell script. `./` does not work. Of course it has the executable flag on and file starts with `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 80):

These are the prerequisites of directly using the script name:

1. Add the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) at the very top.
2. Use `chmod u+x scriptname` to make the script executable (where `scriptname` is the name of your script).
3. Place the script under `/usr/local/bin` folder.

   - **Note:** I suggest placing it under `/usr/local/bin` because most likely that path will be already added to your `PATH` variable.
4. Run the script using just its name, `scriptname`.

If you don't have access to `/usr/local/bin` then do the following:

1. Create a folder in your home directory and call it `bin`.
2. Do `ls -lA` on your home directory, to identify the start-up script your shell is using. It should be either `.profile` or `.bashrc`.
3. Once you have identified the start up script, add the following line:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
   ```
4. Once added, source your start-up script or log out and log back in.

   To source, put `.` followed by a space and then your start-up script name, e.g. `. .profile` or `. .bashrc`
5. Run the script using just its name, `scriptname`.

Comment: I dont know what the problem with the system is. I created a new shell script named "hello" with just an "echo "hello" " in it. I changed its permissions and tried ./hello. It dosn't work. it says-

Comment: What changes have you made to your start up scripts?

Comment: i tried sourcing the start up scripts. it says i dont have permissions to do so.

Comment: That doesn't look right. The start up scripts should be in your home directory. Make sure you are in your home directory when you source them.

Comment: I dont seem to have permissions to do this. I checked the home folder. It has the .bashrc file. But if I try to source it it says "Permission denied"

Comment: Can you update the permission of your .bashrc file? Try giving it a full permission for test purposes using `chmod 777 .bashrc`

Comment: I tried that, and tried sourcing it. Says I can't use the "." command. Then I tried editing the .bashcr file itself and then running the shell script. Nothing happened.

Comment: if you have updated the .bashrc file and have added ur script directory to your path then just log out and log back in. The bachrc file gets sourced everytime you log in.

Comment: Your home directory might be mounted with the noexec option, which will prevent you from executing it the way that you want to.

Comment: `myscripts` is unconventional and you spell it differently (singular vs plural) in different places. A more common arrangement is to call it `bin` just like the directories for system binaries.

Comment: Don't use Bash-only syntax in `.profile`, which is shared with other shells. `export PATH=value` is not portable, and should instead be broken up into two statements. Except of course you can almost certainly simply remove the `export` because surely, this variable will already be `export`ed for you, so there is no need to do that again.

Comment: @tripleee Re `myscript(s)`, I edited it, but rather than trying to fix the typo, I changed it to `bin`.

Comment: @wjandrea Good initiative. I removed the `export` too.

Comment: what are we gonna do for windows?

Answer (score 23):

Just make sure it is executable, using `chmod +x`.  By default, the current directory is not on your PATH, so you will need to execute it as `./script.sh` - or otherwise reference it by a qualified path.  Alternatively, if you truly need just `script.sh`, you would need to add it to your PATH.  (You may not have access to modify the system path, but you can almost certainly modify the PATH of your own current environment.)  This also assumes that your script starts with something like `#!/bin/sh`.

You could also still use an alias, which is not really related to shell scripting but just the shell, and is simple as:

```
alias script.sh='sh script.sh'
```

Which would allow you to use just simply `script.sh` (literally - this won't work for any other `*.sh` file) instead of `sh script.sh`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. I tried using aliases earlier. But nothing happened. I placed it immediately after the "#!/usr/local/bin/bash" line. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: An alias can't be defined within your script - it has to be declared as part of your current environment.  So just run the `alias` command at the shell prompt, and then the alias will be available to run the command with.

Answer (score 23):

In this example the file will be called `myShell`

First of all we will need to make this file we can just start off by typing the following:

```
sudo nano myShell
```

Notice we didn't put the `.sh` extension?
That's because when we run it from the terminal we will only need to type `myShell` in order to run our command!

Now, in nano the top line MUST be `#!/bin/bash` then you may leave a new line before continuing.

For demonstration I will add a basic `Hello World!` response

So, I type the following:

```
echo Hello World!
```

After that my example should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
```

Now save the file and then run this command:

```
chmod +x myShell
```

Now we have made the file executable we can move it to `/usr/bin/` by using the following command:

```
sudo cp myShell /usr/bin/
```

Congrats! Our command is now done! In the terminal we can type `myShell` and it should say `Hello World!`

Comment: You should not put your own files in `/usr/bin` - many systems tave `/usr/local/bin` for this purpose and reserve `/usr/bin` strictly for the OS.

Comment: There's no need to `sudo chmod` your own file.

Comment: There is no need to reboot the machine. At most you should source again

Comment: I removed the `sudo` before `chmod` and the suggestion to reboot.

Comment: Best answer here. No need to fool around and do all the different steps.

Answer (score 15):

You have to enable the executable bit for the program.

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Then you can use `./script.sh`

You can add the folder to the PATH in your `.bashrc` file (located in your home directory).
Add this line to the end of the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/folder/here
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have already set the right permissions. I used the command "chmod 755 script.sh"

Answer (score 6):

You can type sudo install (name of script) /usr/local/bin/(what you want to type to execute said script)

ex: `sudo install quickcommit.sh /usr/local/bin/quickcommit`
enter password

now can run without .sh and in any directory

Comment: ... Provided you also previously made sure the file is readable and executable for everyone. `chmod a+x quickcommit.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Add . (current directory) to your PATH variable.
You can do this by editing your .profile file.
put following line in your .profile file
`PATH=$PATH:.`

Just make sure to add Shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) line at the starting of your script and make the script executable(using `chmod +x <File Name>`).

Comment: **Don't do this.** There are good reasons to *not* have the current directory on your `PATH`. It makes it too easy - especially for beginners - to accidentally shadow crucial system commands, or worse, to be tricked into executing somebody else's commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my backup script that will give you the idea and the automation:

Server: Ubuntu 16.04
PHP: 7.0
Apache2, Mysql etc...

```
# Make Shell Backup Script - Bash Backup Script
    nano /home/user/bash/backupscript.sh
        #!/bin/bash
        # Backup All Start
        mkdir /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/etc_rest.zip /etc -x "*apache2*" -x "*php*" -x "*mysql*"
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/etc_apache2.zip /etc/apache2
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/etc_php.zip /etc/php
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/etc_mysql.zip /etc/mysql
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/var_www_rest.zip /var/www -x "*html*"
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/var_www_html.zip /var/www/html
        sudo zip -ry /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/home_user.zip /home/user -x "*backup*"
        # Backup All End
        echo "Backup Completed Successfully!"
        echo "Location: /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"

    chmod +x /home/user/bash/backupscript.sh
    sudo ln -s /home/user/bash/backupscript.sh /usr/bin/backupscript
```

change /home/user to your user directory and type: **backupscript** anywhere on terminal to run the script! (assuming that /usr/bin is in your path)

Answer (score 0):

Enter `"#!/bin/sh"` before script.
Then save it as `script.sh` for example.
copy it to     `$HOME/bin`     or     `$HOME/usr/bin`
The directory can be different on different linux distros but they end with     `'bin'`     and are in home directory
    `cd $HOME/bin`     or     `$HOME/usr/bin`
Type     `chmod 700 script.sh`
And you can run it just by typing     `run.sh`     on terminal.
If it not work, try     `chmod +x run.sh`  instead of  `chmod 700 run.sh`

Comment: The parts of this answer that don't restate information from very old existing answers are confused.

Answer (score 0):

Make any file as executable

---

Let's say you have an executable file called migrate_linux_amd64 and you want to run this file as a command like "migrate"

1. First test the executable file from the file location:

```
[oracle@localhost]$ ./migrate.linux-amd64 
Usage: migrate OPTIONS COMMAND [arg...]
       migrate [ -version | -help ]

Options:
  -source          Location of the migrations (driver://url)
  -path            Shorthand for -source=file://path 
  -database        Run migrations against this database (driver://url)
  -prefetch N      Number of migrations to load in advance before executing (default 10)
  -lock-timeout N  Allow N seconds to acquire database lock (default 15)
  -verbose         Print verbose logging
  -version         Print version
  -help            Print usage

Commands:
  goto V       Migrate to version V
  up [N]       Apply all or N up migrations
  down [N]     Apply all or N down migrations
  drop         Drop everyting inside database
  force V      Set version V but don't run migration (ignores dirty state)
  version      Print current migration version
```

2. Make sure you have execute privileges on the file
       `-rwxr-xr-x  1 oracle oinstall   7473971 May 18  2017 migrate.linux-amd64`
       if not, run `chmod +x migrate.linux-amd64`
3. Then copy your file to `/usr/local/bin`. This directory is owned by root, use sudo or switch to root and perform the following operation

```
sudo cp migrate.linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin
sudo chown oracle:oracle /user/local/bin/migrate.linux.amd64
```

4. Then create a symbolic link like below

```
sudo ln /usr/local/bin/migrate.linux.amd64 /usr/local/bin/migrate
sudo chown oracle:oracle /usr/local/bin/migrate
```

5. Finally add /usr/local/bin to your path or user profile

```
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

6. Then run the command as "migrate"

```
[oracle@localhost]$ migrate
Usage: migrate OPTIONS COMMAND [arg...]
       migrate [ -version | -help ]

Options:
  -source          Location of the migrations (driver://url)
  -path            Shorthand for -source=file://path 
  -database        Run migrations against this database (driver://url)
  -prefetch N      Number of migrations to load in advance before executing (default 10)
  -lock-timeout N  Allow N seconds to acquire database lock (default 15)
  -verbose         Print verbose logging
  -version         Print version
  -help            Print usage

Commands:
  goto V       Migrate to version V
  up [N]       Apply all or N up migrations
  down [N]     Apply all or N down migrations
  drop         Drop everyting inside database
  force V      Set version V but don't run migration (ignores dirty state)
  version      Print current migration version
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the script file as executable by using file's properties
2. Create alias for the executable in ~/.bashrc. `alias <alias namme> = <full script file path>'`
3. refresh the user session to apply it. `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Adding an alias per-executable is not good practice. Aliases can't be run except from at an interactive shell (they can't be called from other scripts or invoked from non-shell applications). There's no reason to have an alias at all if you install the executable at a location in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what everyone suggested. Even with those solutions, the problem will persist if the user wants to execute the script as sudo

example:
chmod a+x /tmp/myscript.sh
sudo ln -s /tmp/myscript.sh /usr/local/bin/myscript

typing myscript would work but typing sudo myscript would return command not found.

As sudo you would have to still type sudo sh myscript or sudo bash myscript.

I can't think of a solution around this.

Comment: You can enclose code fragments in "`"

Answer (score -1):

Just:

```
/path/to/file/my_script.sh
```