# Linux version of a .cmd file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am creating a terminal program and cannot find out what the ending is for Linux. I know in windows it is .cmd. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: are you creating a bash script?

Comment: Filename suffixes don't matter in Linux (in general).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the .sh at the end and it should work, generally using ./cmd will get it to run. this goes for C programs as well. You do not need to give an extension for the object file, You could then add a path to your bash file and then you can execute it as a normal command.

Look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779980/2720497

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a file extension on Linux, though typically, people use `.sh` (sh being short for 'shell').

You can run it one of two ways:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

or you can make the script itself executable and run it directly:

```
chmod a+x myscript.sh # make it executable
./myscript.sh # run it
```

Linux scripts' first line is typically `#!/bin/bash` which is the path to the specific shell used to run the script with the second method.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to make the myscript.sh run from the desktop?

Comment: If it is executable and placed on the desktop, it should work if you just click it, though this might vary from desktop to desktop. I'm not 100% sure about ubuntu.