# Can't run startup.sh as startup despite being installed in PATH

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I've created a script called `startup.sh` and given it execute permissions. I put it in my `$HOME/bin` folder, and I've checked and this is indeed on the `PATH`. I've rebooted my computer just to be sure. I am still unable to run `startup.sh` just as a command (typing `startup` on the command line). Am I wrong in what I've done or assumed is possible?

My end goal was to be able to just type on the command line "startup" and execute the script I created.

```
$ startup
startup: command not found
$ echo $PATH
/home/travis/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ cd /home/travis/bin && ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 travis travis 803 Dec 16 10:08 startup.sh
```

I can still run the script by navigating to $HOME/bin and running `bash startup.sh` of course, but that wasn't the goal.

Setting executable permissions and a `#!/bin/bash` line per [How do I run a shell script without using "sh" or "bash" commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands) did not work for me as an answer, hence my confusion.

Comment: If you tried those things, show your work! You don't show `ls -l ~/bin` output (thus, permissions); you don't show output from `echo "$PATH"`; and the code you paste doesn't have a shebang.

Comment: ...until amended to **show** -- not tell -- that the other answers don't work, this question is duplicative.

Comment: Showing your `.profile` doesn't demonstrate your actual `PATH` in the current session under test.

Comment: The problem is he's calling `startup` instead of `startup.sh`

Comment: @j.a., ...indeed. I don't follow untrusted links as a matter of course -- there's too much ASCII goatse in the world; had the information been included in the question rather than obscured on a 3rd-party site, this would have been a quicker answer.

Comment: Noted, next time I won't use a paste web site. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is named `startup.sh`, then the command to run it needs to be `startup.sh`.

If you want the command to be `startup`, don't include any extension on your filename: Just name it `startup`.

Comment: That was it. Just removing the .sh extension is the answer. Thanks!