# Why I cannot execute a command file in UNIX?

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to UNIX and shell programming. I am trying to make a command lines text file executable by using `chmod` command.

Below are the codes:

```
$ls
a  aa  aba  chapt1  chapt2  chapt3  newprog
$filename=ch
$cat newprog
echo a?* n* ${filename}*
$chmod +x newprog
$ls -l newprog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxxxx xxxxx 25 Apr 12 09:50 newprog
```

But when I execute newprog by

```
newprog
```

I got

```
newprog: command not found
```

I create newprog by using vi command and I am using putty.
Which part did I do wrong?

---

Thanks to  Benjamin W. By using ./newprog, the file is executable.

But the result is

```
aa aba newprog a aa aba chapt1 chapt2 chapt3 newprog
```

I think the result that I expect is

```
aa aba newprog chapt1 chapt2 chapt3
```

Why there are duplicates?

Comment: If it's not in your path, you have to call it `./newprog` if you're in the same directory, or with the complete path.

Comment: You should also add a 'shebang' to the top of your file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands

Comment: See here for explanations: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks. It makes the file executable. But the result is odd.

Comment: If your immediate problem was fixed, what you have is a new question. Editing your old question to make it a new and different question is frowned on if there are already answers -- if you have a new and different question, it should be asked separately.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which for the official policy question/answer on this topic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for this. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons UNIX does not directly execute files in the current directory but only from directories found in the PATH. This is to avoid an attack where somebody puts a malicious executable file with the same name as an often used command into a writeable directory and hopes that somebody executes it with his rights. For the same reason you should also not put `.` into the PATH.

If you are sure you want to execute such a file use `./filename`.

To answer the extended question: since filename was not exported the value the script sees is empty. The last pattern is therefore `*` which matches all files (that don't start with a dot).

To get your expected result do `export filename` (this tells the shell to put the filename variable into the environment given to child processes) and run the script again.

Comment: Thanks. By using export filename and ./newprog, I got my expected result.

Comment: Boo hiss re: encouraging follow-on questions by answering them. See discussion on meta, ie. the various dupes linked to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296600/how-to-handle-an-ops-new-issues-that-appear-after-answering

Comment: @CharlesDuffy noted!