# How to run program and launch shell

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a Ruby script in lib/my_file.rb.  I want to run this file when someone `cd`s into the directory and enters `start_project`.

To run a Ruby file, we should use `ruby filename.rb`, but how do I run a file using a command that in turn translates to "ruby filename.rb".

Comment: `alias start_project='ruby /path/to/filename.rb'`?

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: @codeforester I also want other users who clone my folder to have this start_project command without adding it to bashrc. Is it possible?

Comment: @tibsar The default Ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends for the most part what you are trying to accomplish.

If you want to use this as a shortcut on your machine, you can add an `alias` to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` like so:

```
alias start_project='ruby filename.rb'
```

or add a function:

```
function start_project {
  ruby filename.rb
}
```

If this is part of a repo, you probably want a file in your repo to do this. We can write a bash script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash          
ruby filename.rb
```

If the bash script is called `start_project.sh` you can call it by by typing `./start_project.sh` as long as you provide executable permissions (see "[bash Permissions](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-permissions.html)").

Comment: Thank you @Justin. I did as you suggested and it works. Right now, I am doing `./start_project.sh`. Is there any way in which I can just enter `start_project` and it runs the ruby file?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands) question should help, although I've never tried it.