# Grep to identify flles in a directory that contain all zeros and list or delete them

Tags: grep

Have numerous image files in a directory that have been corrupted and contain only zero hex value (although some are very large)- among other images that are not corrupt.Want to search through the directory identify files that contain only zeros and delete them.

I am running this from terminal on a mac.

I am thinking grep, recursive, stop searching and eliminate from deletion any file if it contains a value other than zeros, delete zero value files with rm. However- I am a novice and do not know how to put it together.

Or have the zero files moved to a directory from which I can delete them (want to be careful not to delete any good image files.)

Comment: if your grep supports -z option, can you check if `grep -zL '[^0]'` works? use find for recursive search, or `grep -r` if you have GNU grep

Answer (score 2):

To test if a file named `$fname` contains only hex zeros, try:

```
head -c "$(wc -c <"$fname")" /dev/zero | cmp -s - "$fname"
```

Here, `head -c "$(wc -c <"$fname")" /dev/zero` creates a string of zero bytes exactly as long as the file `$fname`.  `cmp -s - "$fname"` compares that string of hex zeros to the file itself.  If they match, then `cmp` sets its exit code to success (0).

To list all regular files in a directory which contain only hex zeros:

```
for fname in ./*
do
   [ -f "$fname" ] && head -c "$(wc -c <"$fname")" /dev/zero | cmp -s - "$fname" && echo "$fname"
done
```

To delete all regular files in a directory which contain only hex zeros, we just replace `echo` with `rm`:

```
for fname in ./*
do
   [ -f "$fname" ] && head -c "$(wc -c <"$fname")" /dev/zero | cmp -s - "$fname" && rm "$fname"
done
```

Here, `[ -f "$fname" ]` tests to see if the file is a regular file, not a directory. `head -c "$(wc -c <"$fname")" /dev/zero | cmp -s - "$fname"` tests to see if the file has only hex zeros in it.  If `cmp` retursn success, `rm "$fname"` deletes that file.

Comment: I will check this out. I think that your solution of creating files of the same length filled with zeros to compare the original files may not be efficient or may be prone to errors- I have hundreds of files each of 20MB or so.

Comment: @kirkinsonoma While many Unix tools are designed to handle text and might work unreliably with binary data such as you have, `cmp` is not one of them.  I chose `cmp` for this because, in all versions,  it is intended to work reliably with binary data.

Answer (score 1):

`find` to `gawk` to `xargs` is very efficient.

Please remove the `echo` safety after confirming desired command.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t Files < <(find . -type f -not -empty)    #1
gawk '
  /[^\x00]/ {f=1; nextfile}                         #2
  ENDFILE {if(!f) print FILENAME; f=0}              #3
' "${Files[@]}" |xargs echo rm                      #4
```

1. Recursively store all non-empty files in the current directory in array "Files"
2. If any line matches a character other than a hex zero, set flag and go to next file
3. After `nextfile` or normal EOF, print filename if flag is unset, then unset flag
4. Feed `gawk` our `find` results, then use `xargs` to construct a single `rm` command.

Comment: in line 2 - gawk is setting a flag to "1" if there is a value in the file other than 0-correct? Does it stop processing and move on when it reaches the first non zero value?- if so that is what I am looking for. I will have to study the remaining syntax to see what it is doing.
Question- how do I run this from terminal in mac?

Comment: @kirkinsonoma Right, `nextfile` moves directly to `ENDFILE`. Test it by pasting in your terminal, then [save it as an executable script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779980/11053344).

Comment: @kirkinsonoma You should [Upgrade Bash](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba)