# Calling command in virtual environment from py script

Tags: python, virtualenv, cd

I'm very new to coding and software, so please stick with me. I am trying to execute a command in my Raspberry Pi terminal via a Python script. I want to be able to run this pi script from the Desktop. The command to execute is `(rpi-deep-pantilt-env) pi@raspberrypi:~/rpi-deep-pantilt $ rpi-deep-pantilt detect` So as you can see, I need to cd into rpi-deep-pantilt, then activate my virtual environment, then run the command all via the py script.

Comment: Why? Usually if you want to do something so convoluted there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple shell script to do what you ask:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd "$HOME"/rpi-deep-pantilt
. ./rpi-deep-pantilt-env/bin/activate
./rpi-deep-pantilt detect "$@"
```

Most or all of this is probably unnecessary. I guess you could run

```
#!/bin/sh
d="$HOME"/rpi-deep-pantilt
exec "$d"/rpi-deep-pantilt-env/bin/python "$d"/rpi-deep-pantilt detect "$@"
```

though if your Python script has hardcoded file paths which require it to run in a specific directory, that's a bug which will prevent this from working.

The `"$@"` says to pass on any command-line arguments, so if you saved this script as `pant`, running `pant blind mice` will pass on the arguments `blind` and `mice` to your Python script. (Of course, if it doesn't accept additional command-line arguments after `detect`, this is unimportant, but I'd still pass them on so you can generate an error message, rather than have them be ignored as if they were not there.)

Comment: I just run those two commands in my Desktop py script and that's it?

Comment: That's not a Python script and there is no need to put it on the Desktop. Save it (ideally somewhere in your `PATH`) and `chmod +x` the file to make it executable; then you can run it by typing its path, like `./pant` or `/home/you/Desktop/pant` (if indeed you saved it in the `Desktop` directory and called it `pant`) or on some platforms by double-clicking its icon. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands and perhaps [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)