# Call a python script with a shebang

Tags: python, bash, shell, shebang

I want to run a python script `foo.py` from the command line like this

```sh
$ foo
```

Using a shebang in `foo.py`, for example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('this is foo')
```

allows me to call it like this:

```sh
$ ./foo.py
```

How do I drop the leading `./` and the trailing `.py`?

Comment: The leading `./` is there for security reasons. And you can just rename the file.

Comment: This might help: `PATH="$PATH:$PWD"`

Comment: @Cyrus Don't give that line without explaining the security implications!

Comment: To explain: if you include the current working directory in your `PATH` someone can put a script name like a standard command (for example `ls`) in some folder. When you enter that folder and run `ls` the script will be executed with your rights.

Comment: @KlausD. `bash` would only execute `ls` in `$PWD` if it did not find `ls` in one of the directories mentioned in `$PATH` before. I had not written `PATH="$PWD:$PATH"`.

Comment: Ah - I see. So an alternative would be to put `foo.py` in something that is on my PATH already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a shell script without using "sh" or "bash" commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands) I know it says "shell script", but it's the same process for any script.

Comment: Yes, move `foo.py` as `foo` to a directory that is in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename the file from `foo.py` to `foo`.

Then, move the file to `/usr/local/bin/` or `/home/user/.local/bin` if the script will only be executed by a single user. Instead, if your script is placed somewhere in the system for example "/path/to/foo", you could add your "/path/to/foo" to the $PATH variable.

After opening a new terminal session. You should be able to execute the script without the "./" and ".py".

By the way "./" means that you want to execute a file in the current working directory. It is always possible to execute a file using a full path of the file, for example "/usr/bin/something_to_run".

Please consider reading about PATH variable [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).