# PHP, system() and inheriting PATH to script

Tags: php

Php pages on `/var/www/mypage` say `system("foo.sh")`. `foo.sh` is located on `/one/dir` and contains command `bar.sh` that is in `/other/dir`. For a user using ssh connection and having `/one/dir` and `/other/dir` in PATH everything works.

Now, if I put

```
<Directory /var/www/mypage>
SetEnv PATH . . . :/one/dir:/other/dir
```

to Apache config, then `print getenv("PATH");` on `/var/www/mypage/mytest.php` shows that `/one/dir` and `/other/dir` are in the path. But `system()` still does not found `foo.sh`. What's wrong? And after this also `foo.sh` should see the same `PATH` so that it will find `bar.sh`.

I am setting this on Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.4.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a shell script without using "sh" or "bash" commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because just executing `> foo.sh` would show `command not found: foo.sh`.

You should specify full/relative path: `system('./foo.sh');`

Comment: No, foo.sh works when the path to it is in PATH environment variable.