# shebang line option does not work as set option

Tags: bash

My code runs on CentOS 7 system, and bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

I have a shell file with shebang line: `#!/bin/bash -ex`. I expect it to work as

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -ex
```

However, the first shebang line does not stop when encountered error command nor return error code. The second one works just fine.
Did I use the shebang line incorrectly?

Comment: How do you call the script?

Comment: I called this script with "sh script.sh"

Comment: @pmf I tried putting "#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -ex" at the beginning instead, and called the shell with command "sh script.sh", it still does not throw error nor return error code.

Comment: See [How do I run a shell script without using "sh" or "bash" commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8779951/4154375).

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run:

```
sh script.sh
```

you bypass the shebang.

What you need:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Moreover, when you run the script with `sh script.sh`, you force the `POSIX` mode.

If you need `POSIX` ,then don't write `bash` code, but `POSIX` `sh`.

Choose between `bash` and `sh`, but don't use both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, follow up question: what do you mean by don't write bash code? Are you refering the shebang line?

Comment: I thought  shebang line is one of POSIX-compliant features. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @Johnzy It's not, POSIX does not recognize shebangs.

Comment: POSIX is a limited subset of bash to enhance compatibility. When you know you use bash everywhere, no need to restrict bash's grammar with POSIX. Read about POSIX https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX