# How to run a python 3.4 script as an executable?

Tags: python, bash

Say, I have a python script named `hello.py`, which I run on mac as:

```
$ python hello.py
```

What do I need to do to run it as:

```
$ hello
```

Comment: You need to create alias for the above command in bash_aliases file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run python script without typing 'python ...'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993621/how-to-run-python-script-without-typing-python)

Answer (score 9):

Add a "shebang" to the top of the file to tell it how to run your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you need to mark the script as "executable":

```
chmod +x hello.py
```

Then you can just run it as `./hello.py` instead of `python hello.py`.

To run it as just `hello`, you can rename the file from `hello.py` to `hello` and then copy it into a folder in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

1. add the following line at the beginning of the script:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

2. rename `hello.py` to `hello`
3. change the script to be executable: `chmod 755 hello`