# How to change command line for execution

Tags: python, command-line, execution

I wrote a simple code for a chat client and chat server (a separate code for the client and one for the server). My server currently executes with the command line

```
python chatserve.py <port number>
```

Just found out that class requirement is that the program starts with the following command line:

```
./chatclient <portnumber>
```

How do I convert? I would greatly appreciate any tips/help. Thank you!

(To clarify any confusion, the execution of my chat client also needs a `./chatclient` in its command line, but since that part of the code was written in C, I was able to figure out how to get it to execute with specific command lines.  I'm not as familiar with Python unfortunately.)

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/python

from socket import *
import sys

#initiate chat with client
def chat(connectionsocket, clientname, username):
    to_send = ""
    while 1:    # continue chat until break
        # get characters from the user
        received = connectionsocket.recv(501)[0:-1]

        # if we received nothing, print close message and break
        if received == "":
            print "Closed connection.  Wait for new connection..."
            break

        # print client username and message
        print "{}> {}".format(clientname, received)

        # get server input and send to client
        to_send = ""
        while len(to_send) == 0 or len(to_send) > 500:
            to_send = raw_input("{}> ".format(username))

        # special "\quit" message 
        if to_send == "\quit":
            print "Closed connection.  Wait for new connection..."
            break
        connectionsocket.send(to_send)

#initiate handshake with client
def handshake(connectionsocket, username):
    # get the client username
    clientname = connectionsocket.recv(1024)

    # send server username to the client
    connectionsocket.send(username)

    return clientname

#execution
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # If wrong number of arguments, print error message and exit
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Error: no port number input"
        exit(1)

    # get port number and create TCP socket
    serverport = sys.argv[1]
    serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind socket to port
    serversocket.bind(('', int(serverport)))

    # listen on port for incoming messages
    serversocket.listen(1)

    # get username
    username = ""
    while len(username) == 0 or len(username) > 10:
        username = raw_input("Enter username (10 characters or less): ")
        print "Receiving incoming messages..."

    # continue receiving incoming messages until close
    while 1:
        # create new socket for incoming connection
        connectionsocket, address = serversocket.accept()

        # print connection message 
        print "Receiving connection on address {}".format(address)

        # initiate handshake and chat with incoming connection
        chat(connectionsocket, handshake(connectionsocket, username),     username)

        # close connection
        connectionsocket.close()
```

Comment: Is your operating system linux?

Comment: I am trying to execute this on a linux server yes.

Comment: I ran the code with: `./chatserve 8888` and I had no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Rename the filename to: `chatserve`
2. Add the following command in the first line of your code: `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python3`
3. Give him permission to execute: `chmod +x chatserve`

Comment: I think I followed your instructions - basically removed the `.py` from my `chatserve.py` file to rename it `chatserve`.  It already had  `#!/usr/bin/python` as my first line so I didn't change anything there.  Then granted permission to execute.  Then I tried to run `./chatclient <portnumber> but that did not quite work unfortunately.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add, the error message I got was `./chatserve: Command not found.`

Comment: Are you located in the same folder as the chatserve file?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I meant to say the error message I got was `Error: Invalid number of arguments` when I tried to execute with `./chatclient <portnumber>`.  When I tried to execute with `./chatserve <portnumber>` (which is not really what I want to do), I get the `command not found` message.

Comment: That error is already in your code, if you share your code it could help you.

Comment: Ah, I actually managed to execute the program with `python ./chatserve <portnumber>`.  But is there a way to execute with just `./chatserve`?  Kind of like how in C or C++, you first compile the program with `gcc...-o chatserve ...` and then just execute with `.chatserve...`?

Comment: Does not run `.chatserve` but `./chatserve`. With what you put should work, but more information of your code you could not help

Comment: To get the parameter `portnumber` you must use: `import sys; portnumber = int (sys.argv[1])`. Verify that your code is like this

Comment: You shouldn't need to use sudo on step 3

Comment: I edited to include the code.  I was able to execute with portnumber before.  The problem is that I am supposed to execute with just `./chatserve <portnumber>` instead of `python ./chatserve <portnumber>` and I'm not sure how to lose the "python" part.

Comment: @AishaAshwal what do you get when you run `which python` in the terminal?

Comment: @HugoSadok here is what I get, not sure what I'm doing wrong.  https://gyazo.com/c78ac535aa5f1abd377b427893db71f8

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm still getting the same problem, not sure what I'm doing differently.  https://gyazo.com/c78ac535aa5f1abd377b427893db71f8

Comment: @AishaAshwal I was asking about the output of running the command `which python` alone. It shows you where the python you're using is installed.

Comment: By the way, I recommend you change the first line in your code to `#!/usr/bin/env python` it's portable and usually works.

Comment: @HugoSadok Thank you, I changed the first line.  Here is the python command output: https://gyazo.com/f872cef4c480179e8a097c9b80469a36

Comment: @HugoSadok Still getting the same message unfortunately https://gyazo.com/7b2e3034925e65cf433cc7b7215cdb10

Comment: @HugoSadok I figured the problem out by looking up this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993621/how-to-run-python-script-without-typing-python regarding converting CRLF to LF, but you were right that `#~/usr/bin/env python` did the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: @AishaAshwal Nice to hear, I'm glad it helped you