# top (bash): show the name of the python script instead of "python"

Tags: python, bash

My problem: I run a lot of python scripts in background on a remote machine. Some of them need many days. When I type `top -U username` to check which script ended and which didn't I get a long list looking like that:

```
54658 user   20   0 7963464   2.9g  13684 R 100.3  0.8   5921:33 python3                                                                          
54982 user   20   0 6243164   1.2g  13696 R 100.3  0.3   5920:46 python3 
98740 user   20   0  737256 508340   5040 S   0.0  0.1  5226:56 python
```

The problem is that, as you can see, each process id has, as associated command, `python` (or `python3`). This makes impossible to understand the correspondence between process id and script. I would really like to have displayed the name of the process there (as it is when running an executable written in C). Is there some way to obtain it?

Please note that:

1) As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993648/7233104) I tried making the script an executable itself via `chmod +x scriptname` and it didn't get any better. I still see `python3`

2) If I do `ps -U username -o pid,cmd` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/314218/857604) I get a looooong list of processes and this is not really handy.

It seems weird to me but I have been searching for it and it looks like there is no other question like this, so it shouldn't be a duplicate. If it is, please link me to the answer.

Comment: How are you executing your python scripts?  Do your process objects have any access to the cmdline args?

Comment: `ps -U uname -o pid,cmd|egrep 'progName1|progName2|...` ? Good luck.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1I execute script via `python3 name.py &`. They usually don't have access to cmdline argument.

Comment: @shellter thank you very much. It's not exactly what I am searching for but it still a great improvement. Especially if `'prog1|prog2...'` is substituted with `*.py`

Comment: if you add the `-c` option to your `top`, as `top -c -U username`, you should be able to see the command line that you ran to start the script like `python3 name.py`.

Comment: @John Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was searching for! If you write it as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `top` command has numerous options to adjust what it displays. In your case, you probably want to use the `-c` option to see the actual command line that was used to start your script. So, try `top -c -U username`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `grep` would help you

```
ps -axo pid,cmd | grep [p]ython
```

You can even filter based on how you run your scripts

```
ps -axo pid,cmd | egrep '^[0-9]+ python .*'
```

Note that this only filters the word `python` from the output of `ps`.

Comment: Do you have a formatting requirement or do you just need to check if the scripts are still running?

Comment: Just check is script is running. However @John Andrerson gave the correct answer in a comment to the questione. Thank you in any case, your answer is useful!