# Python Execution Permission Denied

Tags: python, freebsd

I tried to execute my python file using `./mypy.py` on freebsd. I have used `chmod +x`, and I have added the shebang `#!/usr/local/bin python`(my python is under /usr/local/bin) on the top of the file. However, I kept getting permission denied. I have tried using `sudo` and even execute the file as root, but the error is still there. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: you mean `#!/usr/local/bin/python`  right? as you wrote the shebang will try to execute "bin' directory.

Comment: ... agree with above, but, IIRC, the `pythonxy` package (whatever version) doesn't add the link `python` to `pythonX.Y` (post-install). You have to make it yourself. So, if you didn't make the link, your shebang has to be `#!/usr/local/bin/pythonX.Y`.

Comment: You guys are my heros. I wonder why all the links I have read suggest #!/usr/local/bin python. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993621/how-to-run-python-script-without-typing-python. Is it because they are using linux?

Comment: I do not see any references to `/usr/local/bin python` in the question you linked.  There are plenty of uses of `/usr/bin/env python`, but that's something entirely different - `env` is a program, not a directory.

Comment: See the meta ports *lang/python* and *lang/python3*. They will create the links for you.

Answer (score 0):

To execute, interpreter languages require both execute and read permissions.

Look at this example below:

```
$ sudo cat test.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
print("test")
$ ls -l test.py
--wx--x--x  1 spmzt  spmzt  41 May 28 21:00 test.py
$ ./test.py
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file '/usr/home/spmzt/./test.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
$ chmod +r test.py
$ ./test.py
test
```